# Is it possible to give each li element different background colors in the same block of code with just CSS?

Tags: css, background, frontend, html-lists

i know different types of that operation which i mentioned in the title above.
but i want to give different background-color to each `li` in one block of code. is that possible with any of math or counter function in CSS?

**for example :**

instead of this:

```
li:first-child {
background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
background-color: blue;
}


li:nth-child(3) {
background-color: yellow;
}


li:last-child {
background-color: green;
}
```

i want something like :

```
li {
background-color: // some math/count operations
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible with css only but sure it can be done with lesser code with sass. It still will be css but a simple loop will do all the task for you in sass.

Comment: You could use Javascript to do that, but I don't believe vanilla CSS has any built in capability.

Answer (score 1):

To make this happen you need some sort of array/list of colors, I think. I don't think native css can do it. But you can do it with SCSS (or any other CSS preprocessor)

```
    $colors: (1: brown, 2: green, 3: red, 4: blue, 5: yellow);

    @each $number, $color in $colors {
      ul li:nth-child(#{$number}) {
       background: $color;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>


Js Code
<script>
        var colors = ["#CCCCCC", "#333333", "#990099", "red"];
        var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");

        for (let i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        }
</script>
```